# Opening a bank account in China

Tags: banking, bank-account, china

I'm trying to open a account with any of the major banks in China, but I live in the US. Is this possible and how would I go about doing this? I would also like to be able to transfer money between my accounts in the US and the account in China. Whats the cheapest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Find a Bank of China branch in the United States.  They have them in Canada!

This link is to the Bank of China website, along with branch locations.  They are in New York and L.A.

http://www.boc.cn/en/aboutboc/ab6/200812/t20081216_494260.html

And the Bank of China USA website:  http://www.bocusa.com/portal

There are a number of Bank of China Branches in Canada due to the high numbers of Chinese people.  I'm sure a phone call or an email to them will help.